# Why is my code is 2 ticks behind (rather than 1)?

Tags: javascript, canvas

Please excuse improper spacing.

```
Player = {
    move: function(cycle, opponent) {
      switch(cycle.current_direction) {
      case 'up':
        cycle.y -= cycle.height;
        break;
      case 'down':
        cycle.y += cycle.height;
        break;
      case 'right':
        cycle.x += cycle.width;
        break;
      case 'left':
        cycle.x -= cycle.width;
        break;
    }
    if (this.checkCollision(cycle, opponent)) {
      Game.stop(cycle);
    }
    coords = cycle.x + ',' + cycle.y;

    if(cycle.history.length > 0){
        var prev_position = cycle.history[cycle.history.length - 1]
        var pp_split = prev_position.split(',');
        var pp_x = pp_split[0]
        var pp_y = pp_split[1]

        var coords_split = coords.split(',')
        var x = coords_split[0]
        var y = coords_split[1]

        if(parseInt(x) == (parseInt(pp_x) - 4)){
            for(i=x;i>x-4;i--){
                cycle.history.push(i+','+y)
            }
        }else if (parseInt(x) == (parseInt(pp_x) + 4)){
            for(i=x;i<x+4;i++){
                cycle.history.push(i+','+y)
            }
        }else if (parseInt(y) == (parseInt(pp_y) - 4)){
            for(i=y;i>y-4;i--){
                cycle.history.push(x+','+i)
            }
        }else if (parseInt(y) == (parseInt(pp_y) + 4)){
            for(i=y;i<y+4;i++){
                cycle.history.push(x+','+i)
            }
        }else{
            console.log('@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@ ERROR')
            console.log('cycle.history.length - 1 :' + (cycle.history.length - 1))
            console.log('x: ' + x, 'pp_x: ' + pp_x)
            console.log('y: ' + y, 'pp_y: ' + pp_y)
        }
    }else{
        cycle.history.push(coords);
    }    
},
```

}

My code is two ticks behind, see the console: https://i.stack.imgur.com/tmIp2.jpg

Desired results:

1. (cycle.history.length-1) increases by one every loop (currently it remains 0);
2. x is 4 -+ pp_x or y is 4 -+ pp_y, each loop

Givens:

1. Players move 4 pixels every loop (100ms)
2. I am calling a loop 1 tick

Any help is appreciated, thanks.

Comment: Please provide an [MCVE]. There is currently too many unknown for us to be able to help you. How is initialized this `cycle` object? What are its `y`,`x`, `width` and `height`? If one of these is a string no wonder it won't ever meet the [-4 ~ 4] range conditions. Also, more of a general advice, avoid so much type castings. Just stick with numbers everywhere, store vector objects ( `{ x: n, y: n' }` ).

Answer (score 0):

It appears that the console is only logging the final nested conditional else block in it's parent conditional block. In this conditional block there is no data pushed to the history property.

Only block that appears to be called in the screenshot:

```
console.log('@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@ ERROR')
console.log('cycle.history.length - 1 :' + (cycle.history.length - 1))
console.log('x: ' + x, 'pp_x: ' + pp_x)
console.log('y: ' + y, 'pp_y: ' + pp_y)
```

There is no data pushed to `cycle.history` in this block.